# How to do bootstrap resampling when the clusters are correlated

Tags: correlation, panel-data, bootstrap, jackknife

I have a dataset with 14 clusters, and within each cluster it's time series data with some autocorrealtion. It is decision dataset of a group of 14 subjects.

The clusters are also suspected to be correlated, and so I am thinking to use bootstrapping standard error.

I am wondering if the following resampling will work:

1. sample with replacement from the clusters.
2. divide time dimension into $n$ blocks, and then sample $m$ blocks from the $n$ blocks (without replacement) for the selected clusters, and chosen periods are the same for each selected cluster.

Meanwhile, because the group I have consists of 14 subjects, not 13, not 15. Thus, I am concerned that sampling from the clusters would destroy original structure of the data. One solution I'm thinking is to randomly select one subject, and replace it with one of the other 13.

Or perhaps is jackknife more proper in this case?